# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: includeInTuple in nHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting the error mentioned in subject in `nHibernate`. I recently upgraded the `nHibernate` using NuGet package manager. Installed version is `4.0.4.4000`. I'm getting error in the following statements.

```
IQuery query = session.GetISession().GetNamedQuery("Query1");
query.SetCacheable(true).SetCacheRegion(CacheRegion.CacheRegion1);//line giving error
return query.List<Type1>();
```

I can run the generated sql statement in DB without any error. The same code used to work in previous version of `nHibernate` before upgrade.

If I comment the middle line, application is working without any problem.